# Get particular process CPU usage

Tags: java, cpu

I am trying to get the CPU usage with [getSystemCpuLoad()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html#getSystemCpuLoad()) using OperatingSystemMXBean.

Code

```
public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
  OperatingSystemMXBean mbean=(com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean)ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
  double load;
  while(true){
    System.out.println(mbean.getSystemCpuLoad());

    try {
      Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
 catch (    InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

How can I get the CPU usage of any particular process like *firefox.exe* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using OperatingSystemMXBean you'll only achieve reading the CPU Usage of a JVM. You wont be able to retrieve the cpu-load of other processes.

You would need to call system-functions, therefore you would need JNI.

But theres a library called [sigar](https://support.hyperic.com/display/SIGAR/Home) which you could use. Its licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some native lib or just parse response from:

```
 Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("top | grep firefox");
 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
               new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()) );
```

But java not assumed for those tasks, I would recommend to consider C++ or C for it...

Comment: I am using windows. Above code seems to be for Linux.